# How to create an exe to run SQL commands which ask for parameters

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, exe

I have a series of fairly simple SQL update commands that are used to update order owners in one of our databases. i.e.

```
UPDATE POHEAD 
SET BYRUSR_ID = upper('J123456') 
WHERE BYRUSR_ID = upper('J654321') 
  AND po_st IN (1, 4, 5, 6, 10,11); 

COMMIT;
```

I want to enable our business users to make the changes, and thought that the best solution would be to create an application file that takes the parameters (olduser, newuser) and when the user clicks OK, the file opens a connection to the database (oracle) to make the updates.

While investigating I found a number of guides for creating exe files with .net but none that used SQL or asked for parameters. I haven't used .net before, so don't know where to start.

Using a PHP webform was considered but is not feasible.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: SQL isn't a client language, it's the language used by the Oracle server.  You need to write your user/client application in a client language that sends SQL commands to the Oracle server.  For .Net, that would be something like c#, VB.net, etc.

Comment: I think that is my question.

Comment: ?? Not sure I understand.  What part of my comment is your question?  Please state it clearly because the mods are about to close your question for being "too broad" (ie, too vague).

Comment: Googling "*Oracle SQL from C#*" produces many promising links, articles and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks RBarryYoung. I will look into this. I guess I just needed pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a rather vague question so I hope that this is what you need:

Usually, the best way to build a standalone-application which connects to SQL is via PHP. If you know a tiny bit of HTML, you can even create an HTML page in which your users can enter data and click on a button and the PHP script in the back-end will connect to the SQL-database and return the results on the next page.

Here a link for the beginning:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

There are also alternatives to connecting PHP with SQL (SparkSQL, Hadoop, ...) but I think that this is the simplest way of creating such an app.

Comment: Thanks Jan, That was my initial thought, I have done similar before and it was my preferred option, however, my company didn't want to go down that route.